# Updating App from Background

Tags: ios, swift

I have been writing an app that involves updating several values depending on the time the user is in - I update these values using viewDidAppear but unfortunately this function is not being called when the app is loaded again after being sent to the background.

Is there any way to prevent the app from being sent to the background? Or to force the app to open on a certain page after being opened from the background? Or is there a function that is like viewDidAppear, but is always whenever the app is loaded from the background?

Thanks!

Note:

I tried this:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    viewDidAppear(false)
}
```

inside the viewController class, but it didn't work.

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive has to be implemented in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)`. This method has to be implemented in AppDelegate, not in a controller